# MacOS Catalina: access subdirectories on iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, finder

When iTunes had to be used for file transfer from/to iPhone, the user experience might have been confusing, but it was functionally achievable.

Since MacOS Catalina - 10.15 - Finder seems to be the only option for file transfer.
Unfortunately, only the top level entries seem to be available. In this example, the "mapillary" directory has many sequences, and I'd like to move a few of them only from the phone.

[image: File screenshot]

How do I expand a directory to move (copy, delete) sub-items?